# How to calculate random numbers in R

Tags: r, random, normal-distribution

I have a matrix with 26 columns. The values in each row sum up to 1:

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]      [,8]       [,9]      [,10]      [,11]
[1,] 0.02105263 0.01052632 0.01052632 0.04210526 0.01052632 0.06315789 0.03157895 0.1789474 0.07368421 0.07368421 0.02105263
[2,] 0.00000000 0.01176471 0.01176471 0.00000000 0.01176471 0.18823529 0.09411765 0.1764706 0.15294118 0.07058824 0.01176471
[3,] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.02941176 0.01470588 0.04411765 0.11764706 0.05882353 0.2058824 0.07352941 0.08823529 0.00000000
          [,12]      [,13]      [,14] [,15]      [,16]      [,17]      [,18]      [,19]      [,20]      [,21]      [,22]
[1,] 0.04210526 0.04210526 0.05263158     0 0.03157895 0.02105263 0.00000000 0.04210526 0.01052632 0.05263158 0.02105263
[2,] 0.00000000 0.01176471 0.00000000     0 0.03529412 0.01176471 0.04705882 0.04705882 0.02352941 0.01176471 0.00000000
[3,] 0.02941176 0.02941176 0.02941176     0 0.05882353 0.01470588 0.02941176 0.02941176 0.02941176 0.01470588 0.00000000
          [,23]      [,24]      [,25]      [,26]
[1,] 0.06315789 0.03157895 0.03157895 0.02105263
[2,] 0.05882353 0.02352941 0.00000000 0.00000000
[3,] 0.02941176 0.01470588 0.00000000 0.05882353
```

I would like to alternate the values to make up some new data. This would mean changing every value in a row randomly to a value in the range of +- 5%, while still adding up to 1 with the rowsum.

So in column2 the 6th value is currently 0.18 and in the new data it should be somewhere between 0.171 and 0.189 (and plus 5%).

Alternatively, the value in the column should just be drawn from a normal distribution, but should not differ too much from the original value. Maybe more for large values like 0.18 and also for values which are smaller.

If the value is 0, it would be good to randomly decide whether it should stay at 0 or increase by a range between 5% or 10% (taking as the initial value something like 0.0001).

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first thing you want to do is be able to generate new numbers. It can be done with `rnorm()`. You can supply it with the mean and standard deviation. The mean should be zero and sd somewhere around 0.02 or so. It would result in vast majority of generated numbers to be within 0.05 of the original number.

After that you want to re-scale back to a rowsum of 1, which is easily achieved by dividing all values with the sum of the whole row.

```
> (a <- 1:10)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> (a <- a / sum(a))
 [1] 0.01818182 0.03636364 0.05454545 0.07272727 0.09090909 0.10909091 0.12727273 0.14545455 0.16363636 0.18181818
> (a <- a + rnorm(10, 0, 0.02))
 [1] 0.01293189 0.06799608 0.03552480 0.08015437 0.07834294 0.07845255 0.11692691 0.13262836 0.15728399 0.16228330
> sum(a)
[1] 0.9225252
> sum(a / sum(a))
[1] 1
> a <- a / sum(a)
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to eliminate negative numbers and the 5% or 10% increase. But those are the tools you need.

Answer (score 0):

Let your dataset be a matrix called `data`, then `data * matrix(runif(prod(dim(data)),.95,1.05),nrow=nrow(data))` will give you data that is all +/- 5%.

If you don't want negative values you can wrap it all in an abs() since if a value can shift by 5% and be negative, the absolute value will always be within 5% of the original value still.

If you want to start with no 0 values then step one is `data = data[which(data<=0)] = 0.001`